# TYPO3 & pt_extbase Extension - eIDDispatcher always throws Exception "Could not analyse class"

Tags: ajax, namespaces, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

Im Developing an Extbase Extension, in which i want to use AJAX Calls. I've found a great Extension, which should make it easy to execute AJAX Calls: pt_extbase

In my localconf i registered the eID Skript an it works. The skript is working, till it calls the the dispatch() method of the AjaxDispatcher-Class. Then i've always get the Exception:
**Could not analyse class:Tx_csvimport_Controller_ArtikelController maybe not loaded or no autoloader?**

The path is right. The Extensionname, Controllername are right to.
I think it's a problem with ne Namespaces but i don't know how to fix it.

Does somebody hav any experience with this plugin? Maybe the same Problem?

I'm using TYPO3 6.1.5

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that the AjaxDispatcher from pt_extbase in TYPO3 6.1 needs the parameter "vendorName" to work. i've modified the AjaxDispatcher class and then it works.

I've added the one line to the buildRequest function:

```
protected function buildRequest() {
        /*... some Code ...*/

        $request->setControllerVendorName($controllerName);

         /*... some Code ...*/
}
```

$controllerName was set before. I read the Value from a get-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, the problem is in ArtikelController (not with pt_extbase ext), check the naming/autoloading